# Where to put the calls to stored procedures which do not return an entity (Spring Data JPA)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Entity classes

```
Associate
Project
Allocation
```

`Associate` and `Project` are connected by an `Allocation`.

I have the standard structure of a spring boot application - the above entity classes, controllers, services, and repositories for each of the entities.

If I need to find/add/update/delete an `Associate`, I put the code in the `Associate` related @Repository and similarly for all the other entities.

I have a stored procedure call, that is a complex amalgamation of all the three tables (and returns columns in all thee tables), that logically doesn't come under any of the Entity classes (Its not simple like - all the `Project`s of an `Associate`, so that I can put it in `Associate` related classes)

**So my question is - where do I put the call to the stored procedure?**

Should I create a separate Entity class for the result type of the stored procedure and add its own controllers, services, repositories although I am pretty sure there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: This is the same problem that I was faced with, a while back and I wasn't sure where to put the call to the stored procedure. It logically doesn't come under any entity, so the only way we did that was to put all the calls to stored procedures separately. I am really excited to see what people have in their minds when designing this kind of stuff.

Comment: I would put it in a separate `Service` class (not Repository) on its own. Inject the EntityManager in this Service and call the stored procedure in a method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends.

Having a separate repository for this the right approach if the result type and the algorithm implemented is  really something separate from the original entities.

But in some cases it is really just one of the entities with some extra data in which case I'd put it in the repository of that entity.

In the first case note that nothing forces you to implement the repository using Spring Data. It is perfectly fine for such a case to have a manually implemented repository that is just normal bean with an `EntityManager` injected. This way it doesn't need an entity nor id type.

Answer (score 1):

As Jen and others mentioned, if the procedure is returning the collection of data from one or more tables, in my project i kept this in one of the entity repository class where it is most suitable. I have also followed EntityManager approach like below in my service class

```
id = (Integer) entityManager.createNativeQuery("select get_next_global_id(?, ?)")
                    .setParameter(1, sequence)
                    .setParameter(2, status.toString())
                    .getSingleResult();
```